# Long transit in Cairo (Egypt)

Tags: air-travel, transit, egypt, cairo

In a couple weeks, I will have a long layover in Cairo on a trip from Mumbai to Toronto. I get to Cairo on Sunday at noon and leave for Toronto on Monday at about 1 AM.

I am travelling on EgyptAir business class. While browsing for people who have experiences with a similar itinerary, some people seemed to have said they they were put up ina  hotel by the airline. However, I did not see anything about this when I booked my ticket.

[Visa information provided through the EgyptAir site](http://www.egyptair.com/English/Pages/VisaandHealthInformation.aspx) allows me to enter my status (i.e. citizenship etc.) which results in a [summary of what is needed to transit](http://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&&NA=IN&AR=CA&EM=IN&DE=CA&TR=EG&VT=IN&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=MS&subuser=MS).

It doesn't appear like I need a transit visa- however it specifies that:

> Leaving the airport is permitted for passengers with transit time
>   between 6 and 12 hours

My transit time 13.5 hours.

Now for my questions:

- Is it an issue that my transit time is longer than 12 hours? Can I still leave the airport?
- What are my options with regards to airport hotels, etc.?
- Any other recommendations about how I could best utilize my time while in Cairo?

Comment: I will be completing this journey tomorrow, so I'll post back with my experience

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given that no one really came forward with an answer, I am going to answer my own question. I am writing this answer at the Star Alliance Business Class lounge at departures so this experience is fresh.

**My original questions**

> Is it an issue that my transit time is longer than 12 hours? Can I
>   still leave the airport?

The transit time being longer than 12 hours does not matter. Leaving the airport is still a possibility but in this particular instance, there was an early evening curfew due to the domestic situation in Egypt. Upon arriving at the airport, passengers can request a transit visa (bear in mind, citizens of certain countries cannot obtain a visa on arrival). The processing of the visa takes about an hour and you can then leave the airport.

> What are my options with regards to airport hotels, etc.?

EgyptAir arranges complementary hotel stays for passengers with transit times greater than 6 hours. This hotel stay is optional. In other words, you can either take a transit visa and leave the hotel OR go with the complementary hotel stay OR just hang out at the airport. **Bear in mind, if you choose the hotel stay, the immigration office at the airport will keep your passport and boarding pass and these will be returned to you once you are brought back from the hotel**. Transfers to and from the hotel are also provided by the airline. During this visit, EgyptAir brought us to the Le Meridien in Heliopolis.

> Any other recommendations about how I could best utilize my time while
>   in Cairo?

At the time of my arrival from Mumbai in to Cairo, there were several other flights that had just arrived too with passengers who have long transit times. My transit time was about 12 hours so this is how things panned out:

- *1 p.m.* Arrive in Cairo and hand in my passport to be able to visit the hotel
- *2 p.m.* Processing and collection of all passengers is complete. Start to proceed to the hotel.
- *3.30 p.m.* Arrive at Le Meridien Heliopolis. It took long because one of the shuttle buses was full, so we had to wait for the next.
  Check in at the hotel took a good 20 minutes too.
- *5 p.m.* Wake up call from the hotel to get ready to take the shuttle back to the airport at 6.pm. This is because there was a country wide
  curfew at 7.pm.
- *6 p.m.* Start boarding shuttle and reach the airport by about 6.45 p.m.

As can be seen, I didn't get much of a chance to catch a nap at the hotel. However, it was nice to be able to drive around and see a little bit of the city.

I hope this helps everyone transiting in Cairo :)

Comment: kindly note that the curfew is now disposed in Egypt, and anyone can go anywhere anytime.