# Long Transit in Cairo

Tags: transit, dubai, pakistani-citizens, egypt

My parents are travelling from Jeddah to Cairo, arriving in Terminal 3.

Their connecting flight to Dubai doesn't leave until 30 hours after they arrive in Cairo. They are Pakistani passport holders.

Is there a possibility they can get hotel once they reach Cairo? They are ready to pay for one day hotel stay.

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Appreciate if some one can reply me at the earliest on this one

Comment: This is a very strange and expensive routing if they are travelling to Dubai. Cheaper would be a nonstop on flydubai from 736﷼, or a flight on Qatar Airways with a stop in Doha from 676﷼.

Answer (score 4):

According to Timatic:

```
 Egypt - Transit Visa

Visa required.

Transiting without a visa is possible for:

Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 48 hours.

Leaving the airport is permitted for passengers with transit time longer than 6 hours. Passengers with transit time of less than 6 hours may leave the transit area but not the airport.
```

So yes, they should be able to leave the airport and get a hotel in Cairo as long as they already have the ticket from Egypt to Dubai booked.

Answer (score 4):

Passengers transiting Egypt can leave the airport if the transit time is more than six hours but less than 48 hours.

Timatic, the system which airlines use to verify passenger documents, says this for [Pakistani nationals transiting in Egypt to UAE](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=PK&DE=AE&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=EG&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 48 hours.
>
> - Leaving the airport is permitted for passengers with transit time longer than 6 hours. Passengers with transit time of less than 6 hours may leave the transit area but not the airport.

It can take [an hour or so](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19367/long-transit-in-cairo-egypt) to go through this procedure.